# Bitwise XOR of rational numbers

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers, bitwise

### Introduction

Every rational number between 0 and 1 can be represented as an eventually periodic sequence of bits.
For example, the binary representation of 11/40 is

```
0.010 0011 0011 0011 ...
```

where the `0011` part repeats indefinitely.
One way of finding this representation is the following.
Start with **r = 11/40**, then repeatedly double it and take the fractional part, recording when it goes above 1.
When the value of **r** repeats, you know you have entered a loop.

```
1. r = 11/40
2. 2*r = 11/20 < 1   ->  next bit is 0, r = 11/20
3. 2*r = 11/10 >= 1  ->  next bit is 1, r = 2*r - 1 = 1/10
4. 2*r = 1/5 < 1     ->  next bit is 0, r = 1/5
5. 2*r = 2/5 < 1     ->  next bit is 0, r = 2/5
6. 2*r = 4/5 < 1     ->  next bit is 0, r = 4/5
7. 2*r = 8/5 >= 1    ->  next bit is 1, r = 2*r - 1 = 3/5
8. 2*r = 6/5 >= 1    ->  next bit is 1, r = 2*r - 1 = 1/5, same as in 4.
   The loop 5. -> 6. -> 7. -> 8. now repeats.
```

To get from the binary string back to 11/40, you can use the formula

```
(int(prefix) + int(suffix)/(2^len(suffix) - 1)) / 2^len(prefix)
```

where `prefix` is the initial part `010`, `suffix` is the repeating part `0011`, and `int` converts a binary string to integer.

Given two such representations, we can perform the bitwise XOR operation on them.
The resulting sequence will also be periodic, so it represents a rational number.

For some rational numbers, there are two binary representations.

```
1/4 = 0.010000000...
    = 0.001111111...
```

The choice between them can affect the result of the bitwise XOR.
In these cases, we use the former representation, which has infinitely many 0s.

### The task

Your inputs are two rational numbers in the half-open interval [0,1).
Your output shall be the result of the bitwise XOR operation applied to the inputs, expressed as a rational number.
Note that the output can be 1, even though neither of the inputs are.

The exact formats of input and output are flexible, but each rational number should be represented by two integers, the numerator and denominator (with the exception of 0 and 1, which can be represented as `0` and `1` if desired).
You can assume that the inputs are expressed in lowest terms.
The output **must** be expressed in lowest terms.
A built-in rational number type is an acceptable format, as long as it satisfies these restrictions.
You can ignore any bounds on integers imposed by your language, but your algorithm should theoretically work for all rational numbers.

The lowest byte count wins.
Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Example

Consider the inputs 11/40 and 3/7.
We write their representations one above the other, delimiting the repeating parts by pipes `|`.
Then we extract repeating parts of equal lengths, and apply bitwise XOR to them and the parts before them.

```
11/40 = 0. 0 1 0|0 0 1 1|0 0 1 1|0 0 1 1|0 0 1 1|0 0 1 1|0 0 1 1|0 0 1 ...
3/7   = 0.|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|0 1 1|...
     -> 0. 0 0 1|0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0|0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0|0 1 0 ...
```

The resulting rational number is 89/520.

### Test cases

```
0 0 -> 0
1/2 1/2 -> 0
1/2 1/4 -> 3/4
1/3 2/3 -> 1
1/2 3/4 -> 1/4
5/8 1/3 -> 23/24
1/3 1/5 -> 2/5
15/16 3/19 -> 257/304
15/16 257/304 -> 3/19
3/7 11/40 -> 89/520
5/32 17/24 -> 59/96
16/29 16/39 -> 621001733121535520/696556744961512799
```

Comment: What's the maximum period we need to support?

Comment: @Neil What makes you think that such a maximum exists?

Comment: I get 23/24 as a result for 5/8, 1/3 instead of the 11/12 in the testcases.

Comment: @Neil There is no hard limit. You algorithm should be able to handle any period, ignoring the limits of your language.

Comment: @orlp Thanks for noticing. There was a bug in my reference implementation. The values should be correct now.

Comment: @Zgarb  Can we remove the testcase 0, 1 and make the input range half-open? Handling numbers >= 1 is annoying and inconsistent. Assuming each number is in [0, 1) seems more reasonable to me. At the moment every input has form 0.xyz... except 1.

Comment: @orlp You're right, 1 is a potentially annoying special case. I included it mainly for completeness since the output can be 1. The input range is now [0,1).

Comment: @Zgarb So, if my language fails on `16/29 16/39` because of 32-bit integer overflow then my answer is still valid?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it's valid if the overflow is the only thing that prevents it from working correctly.

Comment: ___Note:___ Some numbers have two binary expansions, namely those numbers where the eventual period has length one. It is implicit in the problem definition above that we must choose the representation that ends in `000...` in this cases (which is also what we get if we use the algorithm with `r`). For example, in the case `5/8, 1/3` we get `23/24` because we choose the expansion `0.101000...` for `5/8`. If we choose instead `0.10011111...` as `5/8`, the result after XOR becomes `19/24`, so this is wrong. Related to [Wikipedia: 0.999...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Damn... This means that unlike regular XOR `(a ^ b) ^ b == a` does not hold. E.g. `(19/24 ^ 1/3) ^ 1/3 != 19/24`. That made me lose quite a bit of excitement about this :(

Comment: See also [What do bitwise operators look like in 3d?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080223/what-do-bitwise-operators-look-like-in-3d) on [math.se].

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, I forgot to mention that. Added now.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <strike>193</strike> 164 bytes

```py
def x(a,b,z=0):
 l=[]
 while(a,b)not in l:l+=[(a,b)];z=2*z|(a<.5)^(b<.5);a=a*2%1;b=b*2%1
 p=l.index((a,b));P=len(l)-p
 return((z>>P)+z%2**P*a**0/~-2**(P or 1))/2**p
```

Takes input as Python 3's `fractions.Fraction` type, and outputs it as well.

Fun fact (you can easily show this using generating functions), if you change `(a<.5)^(b<.5)` to `((a>=.5)and(b>=.5))` above you get the binary AND between two rational numbers. Call this `nd(a, b)`. Then we have `a + b - 2*nd(a, b) = x(a, b)`!

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. Apologies! (note that a link to tio included in the answer would be great)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 141 bytes

```
(p,q,r,s)=>(h=(v,u)=>v%u?h(u,v%u):[a/u,b/u])(b=(g=x=>x%q||x%s?g((x|x/2)+x%2):x)(1),a=(o=b/(b-(b&~-b)),x=p*b/q,y=r*b/s,(x%o^y%o)+(x/o^y/o)*o))
```

Wont work for last test case (integer overflow). Input 4 numbers for `p/q xor r/s`, output an array with two numbers. For testcase `0, 0`, you should input `0, 1, 0, 1`.

**How:**

(All numbers described here is in binary form.)

1. find the smallest number `b`, which `b = 10 ^ p - 10 ^ q (p, q are integers, p > q); and b = 0 (mod q); and b = 0 (mod s)`;
2. Let `x = p * b / q`, `y = r * b / q`; Convert `p / q`, `r / s` to `x / b` and `y / b`;
3. Let `o = 10 ^ (p - q) - 1`; split `x`, `y` to `[x % o, x / o]`, `[y % o, y / o]`; get xor for each part `[x % o xor y % o, x / o xor y / o]`, and join back to `(x % o xor y % o) + (x / o xor y / o) * o`; Donate it as `a`;
4. If `a = 0`, the answer is `0` (or `0 / 1`); Otherwise let `u = gcd(a, b)`; the answer is `(a/u)` and `(b/u)`.

```js
f=

(p,q,r,s)=>(h=(v,u)=>u%v?h(u%v,v):[a/v,b/v])(b=(g=x=>x%q||x%s?g((x|x/2)+x%2):x)(1),a=(o=b/(b-(b&~-b)),x=p*b/q,y=r*b/s,(x%o^y%o)+(x/o^y/o)*o))
```

```html
<div oninput="[v5.value,v6.value]=['?','?'];[v5.value,v6.value]=f(+v1.value,+v2.value,+v3.value,+v4.value)">
<input id=v1 />/<input id=v2 /> xor <input id=v3 />/<input id=v4 /> = <output id=v5></output> / <output id=v6></output>
<style>input{width:40px}</style>
</div>
```