# Bitwise XOR of floats

Tags: code-golf, binary, floating-point

This is different from [Floating Point XOR](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192862/floating-point-xor), and more in the spirit of a comment by R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE on that challenge, but I thought of this idea independently.

### Generalized XOR

The bitwise exclusive or (XOR) operation is usually considered in terms of integers, but it can be naturally generalized (extended, in fact!) to real numbers. There are some finicky details when asking which representation to choose for finite expansions, but to simplify matters, we will only use binary floats.
For example, `3.141592653589793 ^ 0.2` is

```
3.141592653589793: 11.001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
0.200000000000000: 00.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
                   11.000101110000110001011001101110111011011010010000010...
                       ≈ 3.090032203987506
```

The values were written out exactly and a bitwise XOR performed. Note that the result is not always exactly representable as a double, but we can round.

### Challenge

Given two positive (IEEE-754) double-precision floating-point numbers, find their XOR as *numbers*. The answer must have a *relative* accuracy of `1e-6`, i.e., the error should be at most `1e-6` times the correct answer. (The error bound is there because the result is not always exactly representable.)

Examples (rounded to within 1 ulp—answers may vary):

```
1 ^ 2 -> 3
3.141592653589793 ^ 2.141592653589793 -> 1
2.718281828459045 ^ 2.141592653589793 -> 0.5776097723422073  (funnily close to the Euler–Mascheroni constant)
1000000000 ^ 0.1 -> 1000000000.1
0.002 ^ 0.0016666666666666668 -> 0.0036340002590589515
0.002000000000000001 ^ 0.002 -> 8.6736173798840355e-19
1e+300 ^ 1 -> 1e+300
1e+300 ^ 4e299 -> 1.2730472723278628e+300
0.1 ^ 0.1 -> 0
7.888609052210118e-31 ^ 5.380186160021159e-32 -> 8.426627668212235e-31
```

#### Notes

Subnormal numbers ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number)), nonpositive numbers, and non-finite numbers do not need to be supported, but it should output zero when the operands are equal. Standard loopholes are of course not allowed, and the inputs may be given in any format corresponding closely to a float (decimal, 64-bit integer bit representation, etc.). This is a code golf question; may the shortest answer win.

Comment: Maybe you should first post this inside the Sandbox, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active

In case your question has problems.

Comment: (Don't delete it now, just a tip for next time :))

Comment: Oh interesting, didn't know there was a sandbox. Well, hopefully the question is clear enough.

Comment: [Related challenge for rational numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147993/9288)

Comment: alephalpha: Yep, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Title suggestion: "Bitwise XOR of radix point representations" (to deemphasize the floating point representation, which the challenge makes a point of making irrelevant)

Comment: @OvinusReal I really think they should make the sandbox more standing-out, as I ignore it in my first time too.

Comment: @NumberBasher actually, when creating a new question, it says to first put them in the sandbox: "Please follow a standard template and post first in the meta Sandbox for feedback."

Comment: Is allowing an error to the result intended? You said *double-precision floating-point numbers*, and probably you mean IEEE-754 binary64 floats. Each `double`s represent a binary point rational number with *finite* number of binary digits, and XORing finite number of binary digits must produce an exact result.

Comment: One of your examples `2.718281828459045 ^ 2.141592653589793` converted to the closest `double` is `0x4005bf0a8b145769` and `0x400121fb54442d18` in hex, whose representing value is `10.101101111110000101010001011000101000101011101101001` and `10.001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000`. The XOR of these binary point numbers produce an exact result.

Comment: Sure, but that result is not necessarily exactly representable as a double. It is exactly representable if the exponents are the same, but not always.

Comment: If the exponents do not match, then you'd bitshift one of the numbers and XOR them and cut off the superfluous bits that doesn't fit in the significand of the `double`. Wouldn't it still produce an exact result?

Comment: Not "exact" in the exact sense of that word, but within 1 ulp (indeed, strictly within, I think). So you're asking why I didn't just say "within one ulp"? Well, not everyone knows what that is, and I don't think it's much harder to make it that  accurate as opposed to making it accurate to a relative error of `1e-6`.

Comment: @Steffan however it does not stand out such that many people like me and Ovinus Real disregard them.

Comment: Well, probably deterministic is a better word than exact, but I got your point. I initially felt a bit weird to specify a decimal error range to such operation.

Comment: I suppose it's a bit of a red herring to people who haven't mucked around with floating-point before. Well, maybe someone can move these comments to chat.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript, 47 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,y,k=8**341)=>k&&k*(x<k^y<k)+f(x%k,y%k,k/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/tasMgFP29PoV/1mhqnVdjq9D0RUILIejYDLVUKcnTZ3FhZR3swIV7zz3nfny29zZ2t49r2t71NLkaD3SkvtZlKSsg9dGv177Ew8Gfx4MnG4eHV0/HOfybIFOyMXVttBHVqGmAInGiqJEMKlBG7JRU2uyNnPm/VNYJtgctdI5KGV6pf3TAf0ARZ5ApzjgXueIcds/Qjz5/Aizy7wvBbmSeBr@LygpjFjMsi04rF24I9zahhIJDj3fJ6qULlxh6y/rwjlPDZ19xLihKTZ5ZbI9z7jBjLBEyfQE)

`k` runs through every representable power of 2 and adds it to the result, or not, as appropriate.

Comment: I love this one!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,e=8**341:e and(a//e+b//e)%2*e+f(a%e,b%e,e/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLbsMgELz7K7hEAodgdjH2EikfgxuiIsUP2e4hX@9CqkZ125VmQcvszIjpsb6Pg9liP43zypbHUiSoJaxzePuYlzgO99jHlYMuSyu22@Xu@@7qmZedDBcqS1PDOTA/XLmvqnDsUhMHLMPxxv0hyC4hVJg2xzkvsTgwXnCjoAbrsLHGkmudkVqh3pWQBQeJ@fjLxt@TTEPVAiFl1Nbp2v5Pg5dFMoU80UprlLlDsy96Pe/DwZP9DAfhaJIU/LjXAZ372oRvj1YRUaOdtoigASicDEirDGmgBpqkBilqmmZVcWbTHIeVp1@UnRDF9gk)

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming that scaling up by 2^64 will put all the significant bits into the integer part.  The exponent range of a `double` goes down to `2^{-1022}` (about 10^-308) for normalized values, still with 53 significant mantissa bits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.  Your answer incorrectly gives 0.00 for an input of `(1.2e-20, 1.5e-20)`, but works for `(1.2e-20 * 2**40, 1.5e-20 * 2**40)` (same mantissa bits, larger exponents).

Comment: It's not this simple; a large multiplier to allow tiny values will make it fail for non-tiny values since Python only has arbitrary-precision integers, not arbitrary-precision doubles. It's not that Python converts floats above 1e308 to `inf`, it's that such floats don't exist as IEEE binary64. Your multiplication overflows for that test case, and IEEE math saturates to +Inf on overflow.  So it's not an implementation limit, it's an algorithm problem: IEEE FP multiplication isn't safely usable the way you want.  Part of the challenge of this problem is handling test cases close to DBL_MAX.

Comment: TL:DR: for any chosen multiplier, it works for about half the exponent range of IEEE binary64 double-precision FP inputs.  The size of the multiplier determines which slice you take; this one includes more large number than small numbers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 223 bytes

```c
typedef double D;D f(D x,D y){D z;long m,o,a,c,b,d;x<y?z=x,x=y,y=z:0;m=-1lu>>12;o=1l<<52;a=*(long*)&x;b=*(long*)&y;c=a>>52;d=b>>52;b=__builtin_clzl(a=(a&m|o)^(b&m|o)>>(c-d<53?c-d:53))-11;a=a?a<<b&m|c-b<<52:0;return*(D*)&a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFtb4IwEP6sv6IxmSmukB5QBUvxCz9jmSkvGhIEw2ChOn@7K/g2t2SXtNd77ulzd21ibpPkfG7UPkuzDUqrNi4yFPEIbXCEOhIhZRwjdOBFVW7RjlREkoTEJOVdoFYH0ZFOKKLEYUn5TphQtGEINq8EFEHAbC7FDPdXZ8a04/EjUDwRMgw1IxXx4GOxXsdtXjR5uU6KQ4GlwHK6@6qMdxwPPgxxYqYBc1baLZljGCaAriBXMgh6SmLGfVHdSp01bV3OcKRLSX46f1Z5iprso8HXCTtym1UZ6DgeXYMaCT24TiqDj0f7Oi@bDZ68WMAydNnN8HJ4KyekV1EE1Zp7Go81F@1kXuJBcCgGBNm90BA4FrjAfHvOHOb5C9/Ryd/QnWxbC/Bsr18u86nL/iMDvRlB1II7Ti1K7R6iFObP5j2T6JPB5c6jdchenV4c/iBuZvv@Dy24d3D5AkT125y/AQ)

(-11 bytes @ceilingcat)

I thought directly manipulating the bit representation would be the shortcut, but it wasn't..

A bit ungolfed,

```c
typedef double D;
D f(D x,D y){
  D z;
  long m,o,a,c,b,d;
  x<y?z=x,x=y,y=z:0;
  m=-1lu>>12;
  o=1l<<52;
  a=*(long*)&x;
  b=*(long*)&y;
  c=a>>52;
  d=b>>52;
  b=__builtin_clzl(a=(a&m|o)^(b&m|o)>>(c-d<53?c-d:53))-11;
  a=a?a<<b&m|c-b<<52:0;
  return*(D*)&a;
}
```

Comment: Maybe in assembly language, right-shift one mantissa by `e1-e2` (difference of the exponent fields).  The precision requirements are far from 1ulp, let alone a 0.5ulp correctly-rounded result.  x86 SIMD shifts saturate the shift count, so that would shift all the bits out if one `double` was much smaller magnitude than the other.  Oh wait, we need to sort them first so we're right-shifting the smaller-magnitude one.  Hrm, AVX-512 has a `vpmaxuq` / `vpminuq`.  And oh crap, there's the implicit 1 bit in the mantissa.  x87 80-bit floats where that's explicit, maybe...

Comment: It's probably a lot easier with arbitrary-precision ints, but this is lovely.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed, I was thinking there could be a funky asm solution (couldn't come up with one off the top of my head).

Comment: @OvinusReal: I got around to trying this, but 80-bit x87 doesn't solve everything; it still requires manual normalization.  `fld tword [rdi]` can get a non-normalized 80-bit float into an x87 register (after `3.14... ^ 2.14...` gives `<invalid float> (raw 0x40004000000000000000)`), but adding `0.0` to it produces a -nan.  [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) the 80287 FPU supported "unnormal" numbers where the explicit leading 1 of the mantissa was zero, but it doesn't have SSE or MMX for saturating shift counts.  (Or 64-bit int shifts).

Comment: @OvinusReal: If anyone wants to play around some more, https://godbolt.org/z/bP9sKefnP is my (dis)proof of concept, with design notes on the showstopper bug.  Manual renormalization can work with `lzcnt` / `shl mantissa` / `add exponent`, although a zero mantissa is still a special case (need to zero the exponent). At least cancellation of leading 1s is only possible if the shift count was zero, i.e. equal exponents, so none of the bits shifted out need to become significant.

Comment: AArch64 has saturating integer shifts and great conditional-move / conditional-increment instructions, but the 80-bit extended format with an explicit leading 1 only has native HW support on x87, not AArch64.  Still, it's actually a good format for soft-float, with its 64-bit mantissa and 16-bit exponent/sign, and explicit leading-1 in the mantissa, so it's justifiable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the `lzcnt` idea. It's unfortunate that `x86` integers don't have saturating shifts (thus also in the C implementation's *undefined* behaviour). The implicit `1` bit is a smart idea for storing binary floats, but it complicates so much of software bit manipulation.

Comment: x86 *does* have saturating SIMD shifts, but it costs a `movq xmm0, rax` / `movd xmm1, ecx` / `psrlq xmm0, xmm1`  (Or use MMX registers `mm0` and `mm1` to save a byte on each instruction, and define a custom ABI where functions can leave the FPU in MMX state without `emms`)

Comment: [206 bytes](https://tio.run/##fVFtb4IwEP4sv6IxmSmukB5QBaH4hZ@xaCigIUEwDBaY87ezFt/mluyS9t6ee@6uTYx9kgxD0x@zNNuhtGpFkaHIj9AOR6gjEer1U1GVe3TgBhRtGIJFKg5FEDCLxHyOVXKuzzoiHk5PEo7jDe@Cfi02XFpiRfUwlCUpF0r7gm@3os2LJi@3SfFZ4FhWzA5flb7BYtRhiBMjDZi9lmrFbF03APyYx@s4CBQkMYSaYkX9OmvaupzjSPaO/fPwUeUparL3Bl8X6shttV5HJ21ydWrE5Z4y2eu@NjnWedns8PTFBJahy22EF@OtnBLF0hNUS@xZ0yQWHeK8xCPh2AwIshTR6NgmOMA8a8Fs5npLz5bJ36E72DKX4FquOg7zqMP@AwO9CUHUhHucmpRaKkQpLJ7FfQbRJ4FLzWN0yF5tRQ5/Ik5med4PLrhPcPkCROXbDN8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>202</s> 196 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
double a,b,t;long*c=&a,*d=&b,r,e,m=1L<<52;main(){scanf("%lf%lf",c,d);b>a?t=a,a=b,b=t:0;for(r=(*c&m-1|m)^(*d&m-1|m)>>(*c>>52)-(*d>>52),e=*c&m*4095;*c^*d&&!(r&m);r+=r)e-=m;*c=e|r&~m;printf("%f",a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5bCsIwFES3ooIhibfSV9Qab9yAaxCSNBWhaSXWLx9br1H8FOZjOByYscnJ2nGs@5tp3USDgUG2fXfiFokGXiMxEMCBx@yw24lcen3uKLtfre4aOpu3TcwMLNRMGqX3A2rQaMDgsE1l0wcakHJLfJI9PDtSXv@qUhErJXKWRPgt4PBj8jKthOT2GF0ypYF4JsMCA3MJ@sjRPQJ5eXkJ5274fIj7msnnOBbLrMxEla9EITbVuircIk0n@T/6Bg)

What the program basically does:

- save two doubles from `stdin` into variables `a` and `b`; if needed, swap the two doubles so `a>b` always;
- take the exponent of `a` as the exponent of the result;
- take the fraction parts of `a` and `b`, the leading implicit bit, left shift `b` (according to the exponents difference), and XOR the two values to obtain the fraction of the result;
- finally, in the result if there are leading zeros in the fraction, remove them (and decrement the exponent).

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

```
Plus@@Apply@Xor//@{0,(i=#2;2^--i#&/@#)&@@@#~RealDigits~2}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BasMwDL3nNwxhC45jybFjMzo02LmU7TIYC5jSboa0K212GCH59SzuCKyjD4Skp6cn7Xz7sdn5Nqz9uF2Mq@brRPRwODTf9PJ5LArqJL8JC4Z3WOd5YGlB7DYlIjY8bXzzGN5DexqwT8fVMezbV5bfL2lL7C2lbDk8r/1@6JIOOPY86ZSAErRDo5W2rnKK438mylBUYNHGKLWTpb4uAzmDSwGRkWJqkMcE5hJ2nqO8AJzV5@8gq9XkBX/qMqvRud9VmK9UwlprpJMaESSAzepcAddCWQnWgJn8YPo20tgn/fgD)

Input two `Real`s in a list. Also works with an arbitrary even number of `Real` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## x86-64 machine code, x32 ABI, <s>64</s> <s>58</s> <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

xxd output:

```
00000000: 87fc 5859 5e5a 6629 d17d 0548 96f7 d9eb  ..XY^Zf).}.H....
00000010: 01ca 6683 f940 7d0f 48d3 ee48 31f0 87d1  ..f..@}.H..H1...
00000020: 7805 48d1 e0e2 f951 5089 fcc3            x.H....QP...
```

In assembly, with comments:

```
xor_double:
    xchg esp,edi # save stack pointer and points new stack at the input

    # long doubles are 80-bit floating point numbers,
    # with the low 8 bytes giving the significand and the high 2 bytes giving the exponent
    # Conveniently, long doubles have an alignment of sixteen, so the "stack" now looks like:
    #  rsp    --> significand of first argument 
    #  rsp+8  --> exponent of first argument (plus six bytes of junk)
    #  rsp+10 --> significand of second argument 
    #  rsp+18 --> exponent of second argument (plus six bytes of junk)
    # So, just 4 pops puts all the arguments into registers:

    pop rax # rax=sig1
    pop rcx # rcx=junk48:exp1
    pop rsi # rsi=sig2
    pop rdx # rdx=junk48:exp2

    # check which argument is greater and swap the two if the second is greater. Otherwise swap them

    sub cx,dx   # find difference of exponents
    jge good    # jmp if exp1 >= exp2

    # exp1 < exp2, switch around the arguments

    xchg rsi,rax
    neg ecx

    # note that dx is unchanged and is now the biggest exponent- this will also be true in the other branch

    # This next two opcodes assemble together to EB 01 CA. If decoded from here, that is "JMP $+1 ; .byte CA", which skips the CA byte
    # But the "jge good" earlier jumps to the middle of EB 01 and so it is instead decoded as "01 CA", or "add edx,ecx"
    .byte 0xEB  
good:
    add edx,ecx
    # dx=cx-dx+dx=original value of cx, the biggest exponent

switched:
    cmp cx,0x40 #ratio >= 2**64, just return initial number
    jge dontxor
    shr rsi,cl  #shift the smaller significand so they line up
    xor rax,rsi
    
    # the significand of a floating point number always has 1 as its MSB.
    # so if it's missing, shift the bits around to restore it
    # i.e. multiply significand by two and subtract one off the exponent until the MSB is 1

    xchg ecx,edx
subnormal_loop: #multiply significand by two and subtract exponent by 1 until either exponent is zero or the number is normal
    js dontxor #done
    shl rax
    loop subnormal_loop #decrements ecx and jmp if not zero

dontxor:
    # return output in long_double[1]
    # put exponent in place
    push rcx
    # put significand in place
    push rax
    # restore the stack pointer
    mov esp,edi
    ret
```

Takes a pointer to an array of [80-bit x87 long doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) and returns in the 2nd element of the array. Uses the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) (not to be confused with x86-32), which is just like the usual System V ABI, but all pointers are 32 bits.

The padding outside the actual 10-byte long doubles is allowed to be garbage, not zero, which means we have to be careful when comparing or using FLAGS results from operations on exponents: 16-bit operand-size is necessary because we loaded the whole qword including high garbage into the full register.

Because it uses the x32 calling convention, you can compile this and link it with a C program to test it, with the function prototype `void xor_double(long double[2])`. You will need to compile it as x32, though.

The strategy is to shift the smaller number's significand to the right, by the difference in exponent.  This aligns the significand to the place-value position of the significand of the larger, like they were fixed-point.  (This may mean shifting out all the bits if the exponents are different by 64 or more, but x86 scalar shifts mask the count by &63 or &31 so we need to special-case that).

Then xor the aligned significands and use this as the 64-bit significand with the larger exponent.

80-bit long double has an *explicit* leading 1 in the 64-bit significand, unlike 64-bit double (IEEE binary64) using an implicit 1 (implied by a non-zero exponent field).  That means shift/xor Just Works on the significand field directly.

But we still need to renormalize when equal exponents cause the leading 1 bits cancel between significands.  Other than subnormals (where the exponent field is zero), `long double` values with bit 63 clear are not valid.  (8087 and 80287 allow them as "unnormal" according to Wikipedia, but hardware operations on such a value on 387 and later treat them as invalid, producing NaN.  All x86-64 CPUs include 387-compatible FPUs, and we need 64-bit mode to make it convenient to deal with a 64-bit significand.)

The renormalization uses a `loop` command, which decrements the exponent and jumps back to the start of the loop. This is necessary because if the significand is zero, the exponent must also be cleared or the result is an invalid floating point number. This actually clears `rcx` in that case, not just `cx`, which potentially makes the program take (much) longer, but is harmless otherwise.

The renormalization loop also handles the case of two equal inputs, where xoring aligned significands leaves zero.  We shift left (and decrement the exponent) until a 1 bit appears at the top of the significand (normal case), or the exponent field becomes zero.  (Producing a subnormal or a zero).

This handles the equal-input case because left-shifting an all-zero significand will never shift a 1 to the top, so eventually the exponent becomes zero.  If there is a 1 bit somewhere but the exponent becomes zero before it gets to the top, in that case it is a valid subnormal value.  (Too small to be representable as a normalized float.)  The question doesn't require us to support subnormal inputs or outputs so the actual correct value isn't required in this case, although it probably is correct.  This ended up being shorter than `lzcnt` / `shl` plus branching for special cases.

At the end, it returns a `long double*`, which "conveniently" points to `[rsp]` right after the function call. Returning a pointer into the calling function's stack frame is perhaps somewhat malicious compliance with the calling conventions, but it works!

Some general notes on registers:

- I avoid `rbx`, `rbp`, and `rsp` as registers because the System V ABI forbids changing them without saving their previous value, which costs some bytes.
- I avoid `r8-r15` because they cost an extra byte for most uses.
- In most cases using a 32-bit register saves some bytes, so I only use `cx` and `dx` when the junk in the higher bits of the registers would get in the way.
- Using `rax` instead of any other register for one of the significands saves a byte on `xchg`, since `xchg rax,[anything]` is two bytes instead of three.
- `ecx` has many special uses. It is the only register allowed for `shr [reg],cl`, and `rcx` is the only one used by `loop`. That is why the `xchg ecx,edx` is required to put the exponent in this special register.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZtj@O2Ef6uXzG1GzTN2j692ZK3vQC5Qz6kaNACybfLYUFLtMxdmRRIaa3tn788JCVL@5JrDvCeTc7M88zwmSGZMfx8qJ/WVVF82QjZ8vrOPMmW9SRVo/lR9MGmqtWB1dQrfVeq7lDzINiUrGWBKZg83h2VPrP2NtiYVgtZ0eKbf/9I@PwmF0GDlfZ4x3Rl/tCO1t/T1fItIxuoUCW/q7ms2tNs89cTJ7tDwtA3gg5PLTd/seZ9X87M3nVGvzsI@Q7LC5Bved9@mdK5DQj/@uJUETfNipeClmTYIyfTsuKBGmULo4nJ0n83JPll2GQttWAhZNO1gQu0pFoB1cc2xDSnPFwfREvHWrHWMnJRSHbnA9dmNXhdRHtysWp1odwnQ5V4tA522YhKiqMoLA37sWsnUZ0ofm3L@0ZJLtsh9EclH7kUWKifVs/pnWyeTBKrEf4MC1JHQPUt53JFRrlwC5frApq4wFs9GKrFw1C3JZE2jf22xkHOSSLQUWjTogRV50LPHG5y7zAyfcP626bujOUy5AeL@04@/H0eJQrfgjW8ULZKb@FG@Svcl@b/B/gXtcJvME1xkI0hnDyOua5dqcYgBpJoFWleCQPxmFsvDjiQRnct7d/3oB1Ny4VbLvr3FizNb0FxtmusKvHXOsXTcumcyrlTPOqwOHEo9HISxWlKDq1Sac5GQZsLaxzx9qJIHL3SfD0myw39B@v6Igy/Opw9iukOVPQr0LCIRwG/UhyPXHNZcFu5sdDGmd9XnCqlSk/w/txYTJsoff@e5tzd2j/dEmSI3nA5qG4Q/rXMwdS8KM4KVXULkqOZi36MJlWLDE9oVhBFXp0sTkxW3HcSFqyybdyDqCqOox1Zr7GK7YvA8bIa7XBAHN3Zhnf2ytaFDpoh4Aj2q/WQmDGupqqxEwoC8aMW7qrizgvy@PEDhRF9/GFDPx2p5NaypKNWZ4IBX3nKiLb418//pb/eRPQP2lhNwmWxGk7WPAiI0JL5@IMT7EDjQ@dH02Ks@YI407UA8n13ti6@uc@iLGt3VJ6NUwW04ICFhHpZeeXGwMUxBrzStGBlSbzsV6j1wuF6emGPWBRYVD8lZnYDPUi26Ndlf4MvSotKSNwxj6zuHBVI6s3zCAKvBT7ELaAg2IZ9GtJSY7oqK6T4u@926dCkmredlkhEtAIIfuhetVgq2eIm8FI@aaehogY/cxJHXz9zRm@jaPMZ4@fiE8ag5NQ1XoOoB@S3Qgj3e8jz5ehGcuztmwACu7AnO5INRbbSAlPk518@bIZIxjWoaP9mcGbGwB2dcaV5sNZjh9jBY1qFq0eMd4DY8A2du7oVTf30jNHhyQnV5dUdWs0KTEVpj@H47DJB17TCTzmwsuqIZt2Hk8XV2QcIIe0lXt/hpmhuafmnMa842IwGMC5cq1y3APo/rpXVnuUxFM41sMX052rGY6UlvvDhcGsah4MlRs95wpIXmvvJjVQcs2E8YXg40CAYwo4X3yAt1bW4AuxEsDfr8Kj4FH0erOzexF9SU7PCc2o6c7IDf2Y4r9Ebtqy/Qvvjdeqav1Lc/lk9jk8Z9xtEv3BZ3jnu43vuzIQM7J/bGcBh0jKHlvlYMc5wyaA1pmfYJy2az1c02zffDhDr6Wnlr8zCXo7@gTd1yn6l95N7vlpHE3XX0bt4WsDkyGaZCdfwYThxBbcxWYd2PrNmYo5SfELtbrzX5@vFZTfCPg4DJ9WvZj5/67rUaRZeILwZquEdercCwGiAc6xckOvcsjA@x3t0G4r3DPD103mq@PI17PJruLPaj@EnT2cxe9y/TGsW7AW3l7ReYtn@sZUNkNvQMyVuHifaRqtKs7N/JeFd/jVyjWh4MBPD3MCdF5hyMzv9shsfEnOHm3TKwrpMOT/XslXb17V80aLlfwzgbIpamcFmTAtpvu4aPcjWy9jP0GsQ3vOiDr5EFAfxJkqj7T7ebZNtvs/2CSUvV96wiTdZlMe5/aTbfZhuA/gFKV9HaATa@v@DaBMnYZxE@ziOdlEUZVG22yfRdpvnURJnu5zf7EMbLN2F6S7J0zSJ4zhJk22S7xLY7wAJTGcWZJttvguzPAuTdJclWb7NYBzF4TYJk12OaGv7g6LNNsriaJulIdDSbJtFaZru4jQK4Z5kqbNLfwc) Note that TIO doesn't appear to support the x32 ABI, so I simulated it by using `mmap` to create a new stack at a 32 bit address.

Comment: For the calling convention, taking a pointer in RDI (`long double vals[2]`) would let you avoid a SIB byte on every `[RSP + disp0/disp8]` addressing mode, like I was planning in [an attempt I was playing with](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/553429).  And you could say it updates the first array element to be the xor, unless it's *more* convenient to return in x87; looks like maybe yes for the equal-exponent case.

Comment: You could also define a custom ABI where the padding above the 80-bit floats has to be zero, so you can use dword `mov` instead of `movzx`.  And/or you could use `mov [args+0x10], edx` to store the new exponent field, writing part of the padding. You still have call-clobbered RSI free to avoid call-preserved RBX, to be closer to x86-64 SysV (or following it exactly).

Comment: Also, isn't `not cx`/`inc ecx` equivalent to `neg cx`, except for clobbering FLAGS which you aren't still using?  This could use comments, I'm not sure exactly why you want to leave the high bits set in ECX.  I think you only use the low byte of the negated result, so `neg cl` would be shorter, having its own opcode instead of a prefix byte for `neg cx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look over them tomorrow when it isn't the wee hours of the morning. :)

Comment: Can the `cmp ecx, 0x40` be replaced with checking the sign bit after negating?  No, I see, a large count needs to shift out all the bits, so you just skip the xor instead of emulating saturating shift, nice!  Hmm, so maybe you do need `neg cx`.  I haven't grokked why you'd want `neg cx` (or your not/inc) to leave a negative value in the whole ECX that makes `cmp ecx,64`/`jge` be not-taken when you had to swap, or if that's a bug and should be 2-byte `neg ecx`.  Also not grokking why it's ok to truncate the mantissa to 32-bit (`xchg ebx, eax` instead of `xchg rbx, rax` smells like another bug).

Comment: Anyway, nice idea to just use an alternate strategy for equal exponents, but how does it work? You're loading a `long double` mantissa as a dword `float` and then a qword `double`?  And not reloading anything involving the XOR result from RAX at `[rsp+0x8]`?  Surely that's a bug, the equal-exponent case still depends on the mantissa of both inputs.  I'm curious what the design idea was, since I assume this code doesn't do what you meant.

Comment: @PeterCordes The `cmp ecx, 0x40` part is necessary because `shr rbx, cl` only exists for `cl` not for `cx` or `ecx`. So in particular it's a problem if `cx` is greater than `0xFF` because e.g. `0x100` will be treated as `0`. The `0x40` could be any value from `0x40` to `0xFF` though. `neg cx` (which I will change `not, inc` to) is inverting cl so it's like I swapped the exponents before subtracting.

Comment: Right, I get that, but what I don't get is why it's *not* just `ecx = e1-e2` / `ecx = abs(ecx)` (conditional `neg ecx` and swap mantissas).  Using `neg cx` to leave the upper 2 bytes of ECX be `0xffffxxxx` is the weird part. So the `cmp ecx,0x40`/`jge` is always not-taken if the initial `e1-e2` exponent difference was negative.  So the behaviour of the later stuff depends on which order the args were in, which would only make sense to me if it wasn't a full mantissa swap and absolute value of exponent diff.  I think you should just be doing `neg ecx` since you did movzx the sub inputs.

Comment: @Peter Oh yes, you're right. I'll fix that.

Comment: And BTW, no, the problem isn't the only `shr rbx,cl` exists, it's that [x86 scalar shifts mask their count with `&31` or `&63`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr#ia-32-architecture-compatibility); only MMX/SSE shifts like `psrlq xmm0, xmm1` saturate the shift count.  You can't shift all the bits out of a 32 or 64-bit register with a single shift; `shr rbx, 64` is the same as `shr rbx, 0`, same with a register arg.  (BMI2 `shrx rbx, rbx, rcx` behaves the same.)  So anyway, great, `neg ecx` saves a byte vs. `neg ecx`.

Comment: Ok, that's the integer bugs I spotted, makes sense now.  But the equal-exponent case is still a mystery.  You load the exponent field of one as a single-precision float (a tiny subnormal, if the 2 bytes of padding above it are zero, otherwise potentially NaN; perhaps you do depend on that after all and should just use MOV instead of MOVZX earlier, or memory-source sub.)  Then you load the mantissa-xor result as a double-precision `qword` FP bit-pattern?  Is that supposed to be `fild`?  Because as a binary64 it could also be a NaN: both input mantissas are arbitrary except for high bit set.

Comment: Since [`fscale`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fscale) takes the integer part of ST(1), I think you want `fild` for both the 32-bit and 64-bit load in the `equal:` case, although wouldn't you actually need the unbiased exponent as an integer arg for `fscale`, not the difference?  Or that minus 63 to put the radix point right below the leading 1 of the mantissa for unbiased_exponent = 0 cases like  `1.010101...`.  You said it was late, so I'm guessing you didn't have time to test much if at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I did mean `fild`. And I needed to subtract `0x403E` to get the exponent right, to unbias it and shift the radix point. Anyway I ended up figuring out how to just fix the subnormal floats manually so I removed `fscale` in the end. The only special case still left in is for `a==b`.

Comment: Yeah, lzcnt / shl to renormalize a denormalized float was an idea I'd been considering.  In your updated version, you're swapping RSP to RSI for use as a pointer and comment about saving SIB bytes, but there aren't any ModRM addressing modes using [RSI] later, only one using [RSP] which costs a SIB.  I don't think you swap RSP back, so those `push` and `ret` instructions are using the significand of the 2nd arg as the pointer.

Comment: Did you test-run this?  I did with a trivial _start that just calls it without pushing any args, just letting it read argc and argv as fp values; it runs `push` with `rsp = 0`, not a truncated version of the original, so it couldn't work even if I'd built an x32 executable.  (Arch Linux unfortunately builds their kernels without x32 support.)  I know it's a pain to test code-golf asm answers, but I find it necessary to avoid posting broken answers.  (And sometimes discover something wasn't as easy as I'd hoped.)  Making sure it doesn't always segfault seems like a pretty basic test...

Comment: @PeterCordes That was a copy and paste mistake, I removed that xchg (you'll see it's not in the xxd dump) when I removed the last of the sib bytes.

Comment: Fun idea to use pop / push to read args, probably even better than taking a pointer in RSI for `lodsq` / `xchg rax,rdx` / `lodsd` / `xchg eax,ecx` (with a custom ABI where alignof(long double) = 4 so a LODSD gets to the next significand.)  If you allow a custom callee-pops convention, you don't need to push the args back on before returning.  (You can store to them in the red-zone below RSP if needed).  So you push the ret addr over the top qword of args, and `ret`.  Or push some stuff, fld tbyte, push r9 / `ret 16`

Comment: @PeterCordes You still need to at least `push r9` to restore the return address and two more pushes to load the float into memory. Unless I'm missing something, using the red zone would add bytes since `mov` is longer than one byte. I'll think about `ret 16`. Anyway I like the idea of using a pre-existing calling convention especially if the alternative only saves a couple bytes.

Comment: You're still shifting RSP with `shr rsp,cl`, and xoring it.  IDK what your workflow is for copying your current version of the code into your answer, but it's not working well.  I like to use `nasm -felf64 foo.asm -l /dev/stdout | cut -b -30,$((30+10))-` to make a NASM listing with machine code + asm source (with comments) all in one, then hand-edit the line numbers and address.  [for example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245492/convert-from-variable-width-twos-complement-to-integer/245635#245635) or [The interstice of two binary numbers](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245585)

Comment: When I update the code in an answer, I test my current version, then re-run that listing command and copy/paste over the old code-block.  (After manually syncing comments if I'd improved the ones in the answer vs. the asm source.)  I think GAS has some kind of listing, or there's `objdump -drwC -Mintel -S` to interleave source and disassembly, but that gets bloated and messy for asm source.

Comment: I think `neg cx` can be `neg ecx`.  Two's complement negation doesn't depend on the values of any higher bits, carry propagation is purely low-to-high in the `0 - x` operation.  You do need the `sub cx,dx` to be 16-bit because you read FLAGS from it, and same for the `cmp`, but `neg` isn't producing FLAGS.  You're already taking advantage of that idea in `sub edx,ecx` after lzcnt.

Comment: re: calling convention, yeah agreed, when it's only a couple extra bytes of a function that's many bytes, following a standard convention exactly is nice.  It's a matter of taste, like what you *want* to be golfing, and how plausible you feel any given custom calling convention might actually be.  And yeah, I wasn't sure there were any savings to be had with callee-pops, especially if it needs a `ret imm16` which is 3 bytes.  Perhaps you can use R9 for something that already needs REX.W prefixes for 64-bit operand-size other than pop?  Or just use `pop RDI` for the ret addr, to save two REXs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right on both counts. (I actually somehow forgot `RDI` was clobbered by SystemV). I also added a try it online if you feel like playing around with it.

Comment: Looks pretty good now, except for comments being out of sync with the code (e.g. r9.  Also ecx >= edx isn't true, only cx>=dx, but a more meaningful comment like e1 >= e2 would be better to describe the semantic meaning.  Sometimes that rule of thumb to not just reiterate what an instruction does doesn't hold in code-golf when abusing the machine, but in this case it does.)  Also the `break:` label is unused, so it's slightly distracting.

Comment: It'd be nice to get rid of `jmp switched`, but we do seem to need an if/else to get the higher exponent into a known place.  Nice trick with adding the negated value.  We can effectively skip the 2-byte `01 xx   add` instruction with 1 byte instead of a full 2-byte `jmp rel8`, though: see [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/537513) - use `.byte 0xEB`, the opcode for a `jmp re8`, to consume the `01` add opcode as a rel8, jumping over the ModRM (to the `switched` label).  In the hexdump, this is replacing `eb 02 01 ca` with `eb 01 ca`.

Comment: I never thought a label named `good` can make me smile.

Comment: This answer is god-tier. Will take me a while to understand it.

Comment: @OvinusReal Thanks! Let me know if you think parts could use more comments.

Comment: Nice tricks to eliminate some of the specialness of the equal-exponent case.  Shifting in a loop instead of lzcnt/shl is a good idea.  Easy to forget how compact a loop can be sometimes, or not think of there being a slow way to do something there's a machine instruction for.  Can we avoid the `cmp cx,0x40` by doing that shift 1 at a time?  Would need a `jrcxz` (2B) because cx=0 is possible, and a `loop` (2B), so that's smaller than `cmp cx,0x40` (4B?) + `jge` (2B) by a total of 2 bytes. But no, count's in CX not RCX, and there's no prefix for 16-bit address size for `jcxz` and `loop` using CX

Comment: So that would require an ABI change to pad with zeros instead of garbage.  In which case you already save some bytes, and it's competing against `cmp ecx,0x40`/`jcc` (5B) so `jrcx`/`shr rsi,1`/`loop` would save additional 1 byte.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, a `movzx ecx,cx` costs three bytes and would make it work. But I don't see any byte savings elsewhere...

Comment: I was thinking your `loopz` idea you rolled back (for the renormalization loop) was a good idea, you just needed to `push rcx` instead of `push rdx`. But actually we need SF==1 from SHL as a break condition, nothing involving ZF after it shifted out all the bits.  So that's a showstopper.  And yeah the `js dontxor` is needed, now that same-exponent isn't handled separately.

Comment: `movzx ecx,cx` would indeed work, but not pay for itself.  The byte savings from changing the ABI come from being able to do `sub ecx,edx`/ `jge good` and `cmp ecx, 0x40`, assuming high zeros instead of avoiding garbage.  It's probably not a big enough saving to justify changing the ABI.  (3 bytes total I think with those 2 changes and then replacing cmp/jge with a looping shift-by-1 to get a saturating shift-by-ecx)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well I'll play around with it. I think at this point if I make a custom ABI I'll just post that as a second answer if it saves enough bytes to be worth it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Turns out it saves 10 bytes. I've put that up as a separate answer.

Comment: @OvinusReal: I edited this answer to add a description in English of how it works in terms of the strategy, separate from the nuts and bolts of implementation details.  I thought about adding or tweaking some comments in the code itself, but I didn't see anything to change there without over-cluttering or removing some of Chris's correct comments to just explain something a different way.  It's not my answer and the comments are fairly good at this point, although sometimes too high level or not pointing out the x86 reason why something needs to happen.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ooh, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136303/discussion-between-chris-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: I was thinking just now how to describe this strategy concisely.  It's the same as standard (software) floating point addition, just with add-without-carry (XOR) instead of add: align the mantissas, add, and renormalize.  But you don't have to track the bits shifted out the bottom of the mantissa for rounding.  (Normally add can't zero things, and will always carry the leading `1` bits to the left when adding normalized numbers of the same sign, but subtraction can cancel: catastrophic cancellation is the term for lots of precision loss.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 45 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮ≔Ｘ²⁺φ²³η≔⁰ζＷ⌈υ«Ｆ﹪ΣＥυ‹κη²≧⁺ηζ≧﹪ηυ≧∕²η»⭆¹ζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BisIwEIbP9inmOGGrpHEv4knwItil6BNUzTbBtJGmo8suPnuc2MOCeMrk/4bvn6Op@6OvXYzfvgdUAioKBimHTXeh4Yvag@5RiGW2CsE2HVb@xoHKoXIUsJBS5qDmQuRg/pc4@@XfzVinAcv6x7bUIgkBf9nkWVT6EzmPe47L@pL6tjoEPCdNkineZTD6drYxA6ZCxqN68gJH3xPTG7y2V3vSrB3PvGdVb7sB9wM/TTqgSFqxjLGYSf0xlxI@06AWizi9ugc) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: Charcoal requires floating-point numbers to contain a `.`, which is why the link uses `1.0e+300` as the first input. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮ
```

Input the two numbers.

```
≔Ｘ²⁺φ²³η
```

Start at `2¹⁰²³`.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Start with a zero result.

```
Ｗ⌈υ«
```

Repeat until the inputs are zero.

```
Ｆ﹪ΣＥυ‹κη²
```

If exactly one of the inputs is less than the power of `2`, then...

```
≧⁺ηζ
```

... add that power of `2` to the total.

```
≧﹪ηυ
```

Subtract the power of `2` from those inputs that are not lower.

```
≧∕²η
```

Halve the power of `2`. (Sadly I can't use `Halve` here because it rounds the result for some inexplicable reason.)

```
»⭆¹ζ
```

Format the result as a float. (Charcoal defaults to formatting large floats as an integer.)

Comment: If I use the newest version of Charcoal on ATO, `Halved` no longer rounds, but it also no longer forces the result to be a float, so it will always output the result as an integer if it can. If that's acceptable, then it ends up saving 2 bytes (the second is to use `Cast`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Swift Language](https://www.swift.org), 113 bytes

```
typealias D=Double;let c=D(bitPattern:1<<32);let x:(D,D)->D={D(bitPattern:($0*c).bitPattern^($1*c).bitPattern)/c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dSsQwEIXvfYpc7EWiaZzJX5N161UewCcQuiVCoKxlN@KK@Ow1VRabxQMJzJczcyan9/SS9Tznjyn2Y@pPJHTh9W0/xocxZjJ0ge5TfupzjsfDFnc7JdnPy3lLAw@seQzdZ@WhG7gdmPgjz3SDNWH3w9c8HdMh0zNFLhm7uVRiSpyUq8EVlKJFJ91ytPGgDSdSoEbjpTXKON96tbIjXMQJiPUgEABygQBoa7lrG1TC3671qhjv1BKB/zAdpffVRLzepRXOOQsejJQIiC42qpiMUA7QWbQlDcsXC15S528)

Based on the 87 byte GCC answer.  Unfortunately swift's verbosity gets in the way of brevity when bitcasting

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Assembly (gcc, x64, Linux)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), custom ABI, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

xxd dump:

```
00000000: 5f58 595e 5a29 d17d 0548 96f7 d9eb 01ca  _XY^Z).}.H......
00000010: e305 48d1 eee2 f948 31f0 87d1 7805 48d1  ..H....H1...x.H.
00000020: e0e2 f957 c3                             ...W.
```

Uses the System V ABI, but returns long doubles in cx:rax, high bits of variables passed on the stack must be zeroed, and `rsp` is decremented by `0x20` per call.

```
xor_double:

    # Custom ABI: like System V but returns long doubles in cx:rax, zeroes out high bits of stack variables, and decreases rsp by 0x20

    # System V passes long doubles on the stack. long doubles are 80-bit floating point numbers,
    # with the low 8 bytes giving the significand and the high 2 bytes giving the exponent
    # Conveniently, long doubles have an alignment of sixteen, so the stack looks like
    #  rsp    --> return address
    #  rsp+8  --> significand of first argument (plus six bytes of zeroes)
    #  rsp+10 --> exponent of first argument
    #  rsp+18 --> significand of second argument (plus six bytes of zeroes)
    #  rsp+20 --> exponent of second argument
    # So, just 5 pops puts all the arguments into registers:

    pop rdi # rdi=return address
    pop rax # rax=sig1
    pop rcx # rcx=0:exp1
    pop rsi # rsi=sig2
    pop rdx # rdx=0:exp2

    # check which argument is greater and swap the two if the second is greater. Otherwise swap them

    sub ecx,edx   # find difference of exponents
    jge good      # jmp if exp1 >= exp2

    # exp1 < exp2, switch around the arguments

    xchg rsi,rax
    neg ecx

    # note that edx is unchanged and is now the biggest exponent- this will also be true in the other branch

    # This next two opcodes assemble together to EB 01 CA. If decoded from here, that is "JMP $+1 ; .byte CA", which skips the CA byte
    # But the "jge good" earlier jumps to the middle of EB 01 and so it is instead decoded as "01 CA", or "add edx,ecx"
    .byte 0xEB  
good:
    add edx,ecx
    # dx=cx-dx+dx=original value of cx, the biggest exponent

switched:
    jrcxz equal
    shr rsi #shift the smaller significand so they line up
    loop switched
equal:
    xor rax,rsi

    # the significand of a floating point number always has 1 as its MSB.
    # so if it's missing, shift the bits around to restore it
    # i.e. multiply significand by two and subtract one off the exponent until the MSB is 1
    
    xchg ecx,edx
subnormal_loop: #multiply significand by two and subtract exponent by 1 until either exponent is zero or the number is normal
    js done #not subnormal
    shl rax
    loop subnormal_loop

done:
    push rdi #push return address
    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZtb9s2EP6uX3FzVqxDbFdvtpVsLdAU/dBhxQa02JeuCGiJkplIpEpKttw/n92Rki0n7tAGcBKTd/c8d/fwSGYMr9blflak6cNcyIaXt2YvG9aBVLXmuei8eVGqNSuhU/o2U@265J43z1jDPJMymd/mSlesufbmptFCFjB59udbwM@/cuLVuNLkt0wX5pt2MHsFB8tzRhQoVRm/Lbksms1o8@OGA@2AMPBMwHrfcPMTmXddNjJ70Rr9Yi3kC1yeIPmGd83DMZ1rzwP8uYA3rWlUBa9v3l1DKe45fNibhlfwD6zbBjRvWi0NlApjOk8DQoJm3bXOuil85VrhkkLbjSg2sBYNfsvBNCy9hy3TgpHPFJjMIOOp5sygvTY1Mge/C/2ByAG3ZoZMTiCVhAbztlHnp1tMc0j8GQJDXirWUPa1wsKCbKs112baA@xEs7FRSrWDxBUOCrElBxtcFFLkIiWm9KE1m1P41JZ3tZJcNkMRldxyKXCh3E9P6W3YlmM4YCWGr9DCVkd0DedyCkYd80I/dW9sE/qwtkz4M0O1uE4AyzLNjRkZXCbOYEwfIXKhTYPFKVoL@rwuW0O4fS5o4Vr36zhU4NtQQ3ZP45wYJ@dwDU8VFfDHgMOnwI8CDSpRU7hDycICm1wbqFvUGytLW8bBliTaKCxZIVBT2vRiRwfQmcAo@PvlmYJaAxwDF/T7JSYWHJdTu5x2L/1rZDnaMDagEWQfjnCsfdbbh4PK0w3HTu82It0ca4QnucCDgVSt8MyO1TafZqdA5E4hrhpHyzn8het6Jww/OFQOxbRr4Gk35ciBMHNBZ0/kOddcppyKOxTa5X1XcCiUygAcybuqJlzKE169hDF/u/a7XUL14pGyeai2Py@HDjj7Lt0UVJsp1tMuSF4QtSGaVA1muWENEFdMrpXphsmCuxOICxLPKgVei6Lg2PaB@AxXcXsnsPWsxGO0xkC65TScyF5RcWCtGQYc0D6Sh8Q5aAurapqiKB53HaC7Krj1Qum8vQE/gDev5/Aup7GFlhnkGgclGvCp44zRJn@8/xt@vgzgN5iTvtFlMu3ba@4FCpTIvHltxd/TuMFZSauToewT4EyXApHv2opc3FCoRJaVtluOjZUGCsICC4nKZtmBG0MuljHCKw0TlDXVdIrFnlhcR8/vMBZ4hHptl0d2PT2UbNrNsu4S/1FaFELiPbhlZWupoKzO9sPznBh4H/cOj8pX4F9aVjpNbrQ7KmYjcpe/qfDcYtLjAeLm4R6HoOTQ1tYVx2INQ3TPhnQYeJvRQZ1i3KHFj@c4MmbnrwVUzY7taT4bCKh8dHG9/3Az7yMZe/RE84vBRhiD7qj3A3d7zQ26p0mDlyjeQ2IYU2LO51C1ZSPqcn/CCG89Up9Ntl03mqU47STVNj@5WfAoNMKNNWRFLQ9ckncG7xbZUPIXeH4oiqQHROkd/rulkl3DxXcTOIDiZtAjc2EPw2ELGdDgJnURqb6K9ohadOKGaiQ1OZ5fB569AEoYpsAdvihOyXpeb@s6W7dm40a1@@/pqMalBy6zW@syvNYqJqRHv3ptY4p4uUxn9plBK1vKAFV3kA9H@fCeVckZYU5Hz65PWtSf7WaltnaQPe9BZ8enlLvIUrqE3IPuMIQJ3GLbfpwF3WLg7AuDT2j7ebqvKv@Ey/i1acnAcRvZWK@RQ2dXLv0u8D8fWdkg7isOdkIP@zag3GR2Avj08XqswY@hjmoxBrJ7o2f1qN3dd30Zd@sMmUMKj9k/IYW1sNJDZq43FxmOXyvuWqtCs8o9I/ABfRL/iOhCipp7B43wEwPbbSSJn6ND1g7X6djhMj5mQS7HEp2KkIb1/4twp0XDvw1gbdJSmd5mSAvTfCp33DgmktknxTEI73haeg8BhF44D@JgcRUuF9EiuVpdRRA9XjljE85XQRIm9IkXV3688NDPi/ks8H0fFu6vF8zDyA@j4CoMg2UQBKtgtbyKgsUiSYIoXC0TfnnlU7B46cfLKInjKAzDKI4WUbKM0H6JkIhpzbzVfJEs/VWy8qN4uYpWyWKFxkHoLyI/WiYYbUZfIJgvglUYLFaxj2jxarEK4jhehnHgo3u0iq1d/B8)

The overall strategy is similar to my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247235/58834), and most of @PeterCordes's very helpful contribution still applies. This answer saves:

- two bytes by avoiding otherwise useless pushes at the end (and thus decrements `rsp` by two). This also makes a loop strategy `jrcxz; shr rsi; loop` shorter than `cmp cx,0x40; jge; shr rsi,cl`. I can't use that in the first answer because it depends on `rcx`, which is full of junk.
- one byte every time `ecx` or `edx` is used instead of `cx` (which can only be done by insuring that the higher bits are set to zero in the function call).
- five bytes by returning in `rax:rdx` instead of the x87 stack, which removes the need to push the result back on the stack and use `fld tbyte ptr [rsp]` to load it into the x87 stack.

Comment: Nice, yeah worth a separate answer to get this creative with the ABI allowing different strategies.  `xchg ecx,edx` might as well be `mov ecx,edx`; only xchg-with-accumulator saves a byte.  Doesn't this actually return in CX:RAX? (By convention the high part is listed first, just like left-to-right place-value in a multi-digit number).  If you wanted to return in DX:RAX, you could use `dec edx` / `jnz` instead of `mov` + `loop`.  Except that doesn't work because `js` next iteration needs to read FLAGS from `shr` this iteration, and only `loop` loops without clobbering FLAGS.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! It returned in dx:rax before I figured out how to get `loop` to work and I missed one of the two places it was mentioned. The order was a mistake. My brain is still big-endian. ;)

Comment: BTW, the number you're renormalizing is a "denormal", but usually not a *sub*-normal.  A denormal is any float where the leading digit of the significand isn't 1.  A subnormal is the special case of that where the exponent field is all zero (so the value can't be represented as a normalized float.)  The only denormals the FPU will ever generate on its own are subnormals, so many prefer that more specific term.  Except apparently on 287 and earlier where they called it an "unnormal" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) and it indicated precision loss.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I need to brush up on my floating point I guess. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 10 bytes

```
k⁋E*÷꘍k⁋E/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCJr4oGLRSrDt+qYjWvigYtFLyIsIiIsIlszLjE0MTU5MjY1MzU4OTc5MywwLjIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMF0iXQ==) or [Verify all test cases!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuItqIiwixpsiLCJr4oGLRSrDt+qYjWvigYtFLyIsIjtaxpvDt8O44biLJHbDuOG4i2AsIGBqw7hCJFwiYCA9PiBgaiIsIltbMSwyXSxbMy4xNDE1OTI2NTM1ODk3OTMsMi4xNDE1OTI2NTM1ODk3OTNdLFsyLjcxODI4MTgyODQ1OTA0NSwyLjE0MTU5MjY1MzU4OTc5M10sWzEwMDAwMDAwMDAsMC4xXSxbMC4wMDIsMC4wMDE2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY4XSxbMC4wMDIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDEsMC4wMDJdLFszLjE0MTU5MjY1MzU4OTc5MywwLjIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMF0sWzFlKzMwMCwxXSxbMWUrMzAwLDRlKzI5OV0sWzAuMSwwLjFdXSJd)

For the `0.002000000000000001 ^ 0.002` test case, it unfortunately fails because it seems to automatically round it to `0.002`. It does work with three zeros removed, though. This seems to be a problem with `sympy.nsimplify`:

```
>>> sympy.nsimplify(0.002000000000000001, rational=True)
1/500
>>> sympy.nsimplify(0.002000000000001, rational=True)
2000000000001/1000000000000000
```

(from Python REPL)

### How?

```
k⁋E*÷꘍k⁋E/
k⁋         # Push 1024
  E        # Push 2**1024
   *       # Multiply the (implicit) input pair by that
    ÷      # Push both elements of the multiplied pair to the stack
     ꘍     # Bitwise XOR them
      k⁋E/ # Divide by 2**1024
```

Comment: @PeterCordes By the way, it is *not* broken for the `1e300` test case. It is only broken for the `0.002000000000000001` case due to an issue with Sympy. Also, `1.2e-20, 1.5e-20` does *not* wrongly give `0.0`, it gives `2.678658729691487e-20`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just commented after seeing you say it was a port of those other two answers, reposted my comment from there under the assumption it would have the same bug, to maybe get your attention while you were still here.  I guess Vyxal uses or lets you use rational numbers instead of straight IEEE binary64 floating point?  That could let it work for huge numbers, but tiny inputs below 2^-64 or 2^-100 would still not have all their significant bits in the integer part unless you use a multiplier like 2^1022

Comment: @PeterCordes Vyxal uses Sympy under the hood, and I believe it's because Sympy works on rationals. But I don't know. I will change it to `2^1022`, it will only add 3 bytes.

Comment: (And BTW, Kevin's answer works for 1.2e-20 because he used 2^100 instead of 2^64.  But 1.2e-40 has the same problem as the original Python answer, and yes I tested those.)  Anyway, cool, that'd work with Python's arbitrary precision integers.  You should probably add some text to your answer to explain why this works, despite the other answers only working in about half the exponent range of IEEE double inputs, with the multiplier determining where that slice is located.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 51 bytes

```julia
f(a,b,e=8^341.)=e>0&&(a÷e+b÷e)%2*e+f(a%e,b%e,e/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDfSvNAEMXv8xRjwZJ8TdaZ2f9CeulTSCFtt5CPEEtawQvfywfwweok0YqIAxvYM7@ZPSf/n7u2oZfL5ZA35bZMddhoQ6qo0xqXy7x5f0urrXyKW/6XVgLdpnIrJ91xcTk8DdBC28OQmn3X9umUFxlIjat2UMOxGU5J5Q/dU3N2poTTsWvPeVvCsHjcvFbrRTHzg7CTgfl6HNr@3PX5pEC9huELu6lhB8vllVjs28PhHhaysdoVWer3F4INMFRr0JlWZMhGdlbbEH3UY@uXJihlrDwFDuMxNqKxf6GorPcOo/esDTN6nRF@lQyhomnjVVOUoULkqYdI7meFeSmidtoIzvK6vGbJzmP4o@hzyxQwKOe1I699DMGgtjZVFDNKKz1ZmY1Mt2/RJI5xaij2Go1nCcI@OA4zOQa4xsDMqxCC5EXLTEgUUqVHwCodkIIjJ25IfpPon64MO8deojExazsOfAA)

port of [m90's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247204/98541)

I tried so many things but always landed on 51 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 87 bytes

```c
typedef double d;d c=1LL<<32;d x(d a,d b){return((long long)(a*c)^(long long)(b*c))/c;}
```

In the spirit of the Python answer above, converts to a fixed point integer and does the XOR, before converting back. It only has 32 bits of precision to either side of the decimal point, assuming `long long` is 64 bits wide, which is exactly the worst precision allowed by the challenge (1e-6). Because of this, the 1e300 answers overflow.

If your platform has 64-bit `long`s 11 bytes can be saved, for a total of 76 bytes:

```c
typedef double d;d c=1L<<32;d x(d a,d b){return((long)(a*c)^(long)(b*c))/c;}
```

Comment: The x86-64 System V ABI uses 64-bit `long`  (as on Linux / MacOS / any non-Windows, including https://tio.run/).  So do most C implementations for 64-bit ISAs outside of Windows.  To use that as your main answer, you really only need one such implementation to exist (meta rules say answers must work on at least one implementation), but in this case it's also widespread.

Comment: *It only has 32 bits of precision to either side of the decimal point* - no, *floating* point can have the decimal point (err binary radix point) anywhere relative to the mantissa.  `1.23e-20` has all 53 mantissa bits representing the fractional part, with many zeros above it.  e.g. have a look at how 32-bit float represents `1.23E-20` on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html, as a mantissa of `1.815159559249878` multiplied by `2^{-67}` encoded by the exponent field separately.  Your 32:32 sounds like [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: And BTW, the Python answer that inspired your answer is also wrong.  Even arbitrary-precision Python math can't save it from the overflow in double-precision multiply, and thus even a huge multiplier like `2**1022` couldn't make it correct.  (Unfortunately I wasn't thinking when I upvoted it; now I can't downvote until it's edited.)

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VoUIjUSdJU0MjJz8vXQFEaGokaiVrxiELJAEFNPWTuVLyS5NyUhWSbQ19fGxsjI2s/@cmZuZpaFZzFRRl5pWkaSippsXkKelUaBjrGZoYmloamZkam1pYmlsap2obGOgYYRPV1LTmqv0PAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
∩√=êⁿ;r⌂$══▓ìêCO¥ÇnµtƒÉd+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=effb3d88fc3b727f24cdcdb28d88434f9d806ee6749f90642b&i=1.0+2.0%0A3.141592653589793+2.141592653589793%0A2.718281828459045+2.141592653589793%0A1000000000.0+0.1%0A0.002+0.0016666666666666668%0A0.002000000000000001+0.002%0A1e300+1.0%0A1e300+4e299%0A0.1+0.1%0A7.888609052210118e-31+5.380186160021159e-32&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 96 bytes

```c
#define D double
#define P*(long*)
D z;D f(D x,D y){P&z=P&x^P&y;z=x>=y&x<2e-308?z:f(y/2,x/2)*2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDhToMwFIV/r09xMyMpWFhbYKMi8w8PwAMYE4WykMxikBlg2bNjGRuKJt6kTe/p6Xdumtq7NO37m0zmhZIQQ1YeXvcSXYXEwvtS7SwTxdCFMeQ4hobE0JrHxOiixGieE6MNu6jZRq3RPHBpuzR47O5z3K44aVbctHh46j/LIoNaftR4DNCQS5RGwREtLk0Fkc7Ql60ZosV7Vag6x8tbh/kSxt3ejocntSQDpSVQae8JIe2Ft5dC4TPwHMYI8AF0blyHecwXfO27fiA2wtWXv6XJzJ0NC3gwLM8X1PP/MzN6LQLUYZNOHUr5IFHK1vMK5iY6Kza@@R6dyTt3gLM/iie5ED9YbJqgkvWhUkD13/Rf)

subnormal number is good

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,y)=>x+y>1e60?+[g(x)^g(y)]:f(x*2,y*2)/2
g=x=>BigInt(x%1?0:'0o'+x.toString(8))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5NT8MwDIbP66/IBS1ZS7DTjzVD7SRunDlOIE0ljYqmBK0BpUL89tJ2MChIvJIPfvLY8dP@dd9Wx@bZXRr7qPq@LqiPOlaUPuxKVBlsw52mnj1o2rH7TU39SkTdSrArEejCF@VNo2@No/4Ct7BZgl2Gnjt7546N0TRnrK9fTOUaa4hT7eBFpGPkLVhU1rT2oPjB6glGpJ5@ZtfBexAsJhkjIob@1MQcE0ylyNI4zeVaxsPjb3SWBV9jLvKxklRCkv4nI3wlIsDxzIEDiBEBYDZPPpdgFjzNfJ@OKozH5fiHJEpI@WMXfl7QfwA)

Base 8 to avoid `e+66`, `>1e60` to avoid overflow